# How to run (3rd-party) EXE at the end of Jenkins process?

Tags: windows, jenkins, windows-server-2008

I'm now installing Jenkins on Windows server 2008.

I'd like to run my EXE (a 3rd-party that generates a report) at the end of the process. Can you guide me how to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add a build step 'Execute Windows batch command'. Call your exe in that build step.